# How to scale Excel formulas with dynamic data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel worksheet that uses the Adobe Analytics Report Builder plugin. The plugin inserts a variable number of rows of data. I have written forumlas to appear in adjacent columns to the data. How can I have the formulas automatically scale as rows are added to the worksheet.

Comment: I have never worked with this plugin, but if the plugin can add data to a table, then any formula in the table will autofill when new rows are added.

Comment: To count ROWs added to the worksheet , you need to use simple COUNTA formula for certain rows in column of all rows,, will count only FILLED rows if want to count both filled and blank then use ROWS(Rage) .

Comment: Are you looking for Relative reference?